# Expresso Store UPS Shipping Calculation is off on with multiple quantities

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

When calculating a single quantity item in the store using UPS shipping, my shipping calculations work perfect. However, if I add 2 or more quantities, my shipping rates go up but not exactly the same as what UPS is calculating.

[edit] EE 2.5.3 w/ Expresso Store 1.6.2 / IIS 7 / PHP 5.3.6

1X Item Calculation (perfect)
UPS $14.66
Store $14.66

2X Items (different)
UPS $29.32 
Store $17.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the UPS api calculates everything as a single shipment - as they would expect you to ship multiple items in one box.